# undertanding purchasin strategy and lead time of passengers - Python

Tags: python, behavior, consumer

[ticket purchase lead time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/872T9.png)
<- press for image
Hi, I'm 31 and started python a month ago, R 3 month ago. Calculated ticket purchase lead time for specific Destination of Airline. image is attached from final excell.
tried plotting (bubble) but cannot find specific plot that will explain that passengers are purchasing tickets 1 week earlier more than a month before.
in image attached, left colum is date of flight. upper row is lead_time(how many days lef t till flight. and populated with how many tickets are sold on specific days prior to flight date.
image link is attached.

Answer (score 0):

Use histogram of difference between purchase time and departure, e.g. using matplotlib like this:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/hist.html